# Hibernate Mapping - Join of two table to one flat class

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, join, mapping

I have two tables: `patient_data` and `patient_diagnosis`

`Patient_data` contains personal data of patient like: `pid (pkey)`, `gender`, `birth_date`

`patient_diagnosis` contains the diagnosis data of the registered patients. It has fields like: `record_id (pkey)`, `pid (fkey to patient_data(pid))`, `diagnosis_date` and other related fields.

Now, I want to join these two tables on `pid` and have all these fields in a single type of object.

Here is the mapping file:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class catalog="emr" name="in.Models.Emr" table="patient_diagnosis">
<id name="recordid" type="long">
     <column name="record_id"/>
</id>

<property name="diagnosisDate" type="timestamp">
      <column length="19" name="diagnosis_date" not-null="true"/>
</property>

<property name="snomedTermPrimary" type="long">
      <column name="snomed_term_primary" not-null="true" />
</property>

<property name="snomedTermSecondary" type="string">
      <column name="snomed_term_secondary" />
</property>

<property name="episodeNo" type="long">
      <column name="episode_no" not-null="true" />
</property>

<property name="pid" type="long">
      <column name="pid" not-null="true" />
</property>


<join table="patient_data">
     <key column="pid"/>
     <property name="gender" type="string">
          <column name="gender" not-null="true"/>
     </property>
     <property name="birthDate" type="timestamp">
          <column length="19" name="birth_date" not-null="true"/>
     </property>
</join>

</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

But, the join applies on `patient_diagnosis.record_id = patient_data.pid` instead of `patient_diagnosis.pid = patient_data.pid` i.e. HQL applies on primary key of first table with mentioned column from second table.

Please provide the solution so that join can be applied on mentioned column from first with mentioned column from second table. Or is there another way out?

Please note that in case I didn't create classes for `patient_data` or `patient_diagnosis`. But, just `Emr` class having combination of fields of these tables is created.

Comment: Why don't you separate them into two xmls.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving foreign key

```
 <id name="pid" type="java.lang.Long">
        <column name="pid" />
        <generator class="foreign">
            <param name="property">patient_data</param>
        </generator>
    </id>
```

I am not sure but maybe this should work.

And

```
 <one-to-one name="patient_data" class="in.Models.Emr"
        cascade="save-update"></one-to-one>
```

Similarly in Join class

```
  <one-to-one name="patient_diagnosis" class="in.Models.Emr"
        cascade="save-update"></one-to-one>
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: If column name=pid is used as id, then patient data with multiple diagnosis will be dropped off. We would have only one result with one pid. Also, for one to one mapping, we need to declare an object of other class with one class. But, as mentioned, I am interested in having only one flat class.